# NS Timer Producing Double the Nodes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have this code

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnPipes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
func spawnPipes() {


func spawnPipes() {

let square = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    square.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    square.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    square.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
self.addChild(square)
```

This code works well and spawns 1 "square" every second as per the timer, therefore its spawning 1 node every second. On the screen I can only see 1 square being spawned every second. However, when I play the project on my actual iPhone 5S the node count shows its spawning 2 nodes every second.But I cannot see 2 squares nor I cannot figure out why this is happening?!

It makes my game lag when I add more nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the NSTimer as a property (you are going to need this in order to invalidate the timer to stop it and to release yourself so you don't leak), and don't create the NSTimer a second time if that property has already been set.